# Send data from view to controller through href in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to send some data when user clicks on this link

```
<a asp-action="ViewOthersProfile">@question.Questionaire</a>
```

and this is my action method

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult ViewOtherProfile()
{
  return View("OtherProfile");
}
```

also,how we'll get it in action method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a query-string parameter.

Comment: like ?data="" but how to get this in action method?

Comment: `ViewOtherProfile( [FromQuery( Name = "data" )] String? data = null )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Use asp-route-myData for your data and you can name it whatever you want.
//asp-route-myData2, asp-route-data, asp-route-dog, ... you got the point.
<a asp-action="ViewOthersProfile" asp-route-myData="test string">@question.Questionaire</a>

//Here you can get your data as a parameter. 
//However, the parameter name must be the last part of asp-route-myData. I mean 'myData'
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult ViewOtherProfile(string myData) 
{
  //And you can use myData whatever way you need
  var result = myData + "test2";
  return View("OtherProfile");
}
```